# When i tried to rename a txt file in pythonwin

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I wrote a script to rename a txt file in pythonwin as below.

import os

```
os.rename("northrdge.txt","northrdgechg.txt")
```

the above text file is in the path:C:\Users\gmayil\Desktop\northrdge.txt.

after this when i run the script i met below error:
Can anyone please help me on this ?

> > > 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py", line 433, in ImportFile
    exec codeObj in __main__.__dict__
  File "<auto import>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\Tools\gopi\renamefile.py", line 2, in <module>
    os.rename("northrdge.txt","northrdgechg.txt")
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Answer (score 0):

Your python-file lies in "C:\Python27\Tools\gopi\renamefile.py", but you say your txt-file is in "C:\Users\gmayil\Desktop\". If you pass a relative path, python searches in its own directory, which is "C:\Python27\Tools\gopi\".

So all you have to do is giving the complete path:

```
os.rename("C:\Users\gmayil\Desktop\northrdge.txt", "C:\Users\gmayil\Desktop\northrdgechg.txt")
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply.I can do this successfully now.